# Anyway to run docker rules with custom venv python environment or add cacert via variable?

Tags: bazel

I'm using the docker rules to push images in the bazel build. The docker repository uses a custom cacert. To be able to upload images to it, I had to create a custom cacerts.txt file with one additional cacerts that is installed via module ca_certs_locater with function get() in a venv python2 environment. This is to override the default cacerts.txt that is provided with httplib2 which the docker rules use.

My question is there anyway to have the docker rules run under a custom .venv environment? Or would it be better to provide an additional variable for custom cacert.

Currently, I activate the venv before I run any bazel rules. This seems messy. What would be the recommended way to get the cacert to be picked up by the docker rules?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from the rules_docker team:

rules_docker supports overriding its imports, so if you define a customized version of the httplib2 repo (with your certs), we should pick it up:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/container/container.bzl#L62-L77